# Configure WCF with client certificate signing XMLDsig, WS-Security or XADES

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soap, x509certificate, ws-security

Using VS2019, ASP.NET project running .net 4.0.

I created the soap client adding the Service Reference to the wsdl file. Now I'm configuring the certificate and calls method.

This way worked in the old soap server, but now the soap server changed. I tested with SoapUI using the same Basic Auth configuration and works perfectly, but not with my .Net 4.0 client...

**Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
     <binding name="PLATAFORMA">
  <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
  <security 
    authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" 
    messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
    <secureConversationBootstrap />
  </security>
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings> 
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="CERT">
        <clientCredentials>
          <clientCertificate findValue="ClientCert" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate findValue="*.ServerCert.com" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>  
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <client>
    <endpoint
      address="endpointURI"
          binding="customBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="PLATAFORMA"
      behaviorConfiguration="CERT"
      contract="ServiceReference1.RequestPort1"
      name="Request.Request1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="*.ServerCert.com" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

XML Outoing header (catched with intercerptor):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">peticionSincrona</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:e3a5c4bd-f159-48c1-8f3f-cf22da6b7e3b</a:MessageID>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="035f2491-0772-4b1e-a286-9be30720d5ea" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">4d7f76c2-0486-4a81-93ad-32aecf02b035</ActivityId>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo9ph/BcvvnBFuLQYdch+LyYAAAAAHsOKxYeqzk+Do5pQmamNIPUdiXOiYjpBl1dsV5pp+SMACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
  </s:Header>
```

I understand that some information is needed, how can I specify to sign as XMLDsig? why is not soap/envelope/encoding? I need help to configure the soap client.

The server return error 500 with a default tomcat error, is not even soapenv:fault or similar. I think the request envelope is not generating properly.

**EDIT**: Must be over soap11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the client configuration generated after changing the SOAP server? If it requires the Basic authentication, why do we not need to provide username/password, but just need to provide a client certificate(according to the binding type)?
I suggest you re-generate a client proxy class by adding service reference. this also generates a proper configuration in the `webconfig` file.
Besides, since the server changes, the server’s certificate used to implement HTTPS security may also change, so the default certificate we provide on the client-side should also be changed.

```
<serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate findValue="*.ServerCert.com" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            </serviceCertificate>
```

Mutual certificate authentication requires a trust relationship between the client and the server.

```
<security 
    authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex"
```

Not only do we need to install a client certificate on the new server in order to trust the client, we also need to install the server’s certificate on the client-side.
For details,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hello Abraham, thanks for your reply. I have installed both certificates client and server. I am using the configuration generated by the proxy class, but modified to add MutualCertificate and client/server certificate. This configuration is working because I was using it previously. I think the problmen is the request XML envelope generated. Or at least I need to sign the envelope with my private certificate and trust server certificate (which I already have).

Comment: Using public key encryption and private key to sign the message is done by the WCF framework.  no necessary to manually set it. We just provide credentials based on the binding type and set the certificate(if the certificate needed) while calling the service.

Comment: But with that configuration, I'm having this issue:
`System.ServiceModel.FaultException 1: '0307 No se ha encontrado el nodo firma'` which means, It can't find the signature node.

Comment: I managed to get working as you said, but now I get erros like soapfault:12, can't change the message version to soap11.

Comment: Try the SOAP11 or SOAP11WSAddressingAugust2004, Please share the solution if you have solved the issue so that enable us learn more.

Comment: It didn't work. I gave up this asduhasdiuahduia project. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will accept your answer as valid but the problem was that the destination service is not updated to accept this kind of WCF security. They told to program in Java with those techonologies but I can do a simple httpclient and creating headers manually, but still complicated.